# Electric brushed motor for electric car project

Tags: electric-machine

I am using a 24v 11amp 5700 rpm motor for a single seater car project. 
The problem is that when i am connecting the motor directly to the batteries without any throttle or control the vehicle shaft moves a little and wires starts to burn out
On checking in clamp meter it is giving 143Amp 
Now can any one tell whats the problem here?

Comment: The motor is stalled. Please edit your question to explain what obvious checks you have carried out. Can you turn the motor by hand? Can you turn the motor by pushing the vehicle? What is the motor resistance? What is the motor part number and can you provide a link to the datasheet? Otherwise you are asking us to guess.

Comment: If you use the throttle control, what happens? It is normal for a DC motor to take a high current when first starting. A throttle control would prevent that. However if 143 amps does not move the vehicle, there is something seriously wrong.

Comment: @Charles Crowe, not all those amps make torque. once the iron is saturated pileing extra amps on only adds minescule amounts of torque.

Comment: @Jason, I assumed that the motor was something like a automotive cranking motor that would deliver torque pretty much in proportion to current at the level mentioned. However this question falls far short of including enough information to make possible a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Stack Exchange!  A 24-volt, 11 amp motor has an input of 24 * 11 or 264 watts.  Assuming (charitably) 90% efficiency, you have 238 watts of output power. At 5700 rpm, this much power means that you have torque of only 0.4 N-m.  You can probably stall this with your fingers.

A fractional horsepower motor (yours is less than 1/4 hp) is not going to be adequate for a human-sized car.  When the motor is stalled, the current is only limited by the resistance of the windings, and since you are not making any mechanical power, all goes into heat.

Comment: Before when we were testing it,  it was not burning wires and ,but that all testing was via controller we made using mi-rio and throttle control.

Comment: Now we are just installing the motor to the chassis and directly connecting the switch of motor to battery without any controller or anything in between

Comment: Did your controller implement current limiting?  When you were testing it before did you have a load on the motor?

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t have a variable speed transmission, you likely are stalling the motor. 1/4 Hp is not enough to accelerate your weight to full speed where start current is typically 10x rated current but yours must be very efficient so it is 13x rated current.

I suspect the problem is your gear ratios or mechanical design.

Have you ever tried starting a car in 5th gear? Or a bicycle in 10th gear.